# XCode: Updating Score label restarts/ brings my everything back to starting position

Tags: ios, xcode, label, project, reset

File:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9q35un4f70k4n2/FlappyBirdTutorial.zip

Youtube Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiyhXsH9d6A

I am working on a project similar to this file. This file and my own both have the same issue when updating the label for the score.

Every time the score is to be updated it will reset everything to the starting position.

My guesses:

1. Error due to Xcode bug.
2. Due to subview/ label conflicts.
3. Inproper syntax

Comment: it's better to put your code that you have question instead link